# Reference in Coq Lists library not found

Tags: coq

I'm trying to use the `concat` function as it appears in https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html. I tried the following:

```
Require Import Arith Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition CON (l : list nat):= (concat [[0]; l]).
```

but I get the error `Error: The reference concat was not found in the current environment.` I thought this should work since I've already imported the library, so I don't know where this error comes from.

I'm using version 8.4pl3 (January 2014). Could be a version issue?

Comment: Most probably, yes. I don't know when concat has been added, but it was after 8.4pl3

Comment: Yes, it's a version issue. It's not in the library as of Coq 8.4pl6, but it is present in Coq 8.5pl1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat` was added in [this](https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/64789ead3540e37983759b25de39233dcbf82b23) commit. I think it was close to the end of the 8.4pl3 release so it was not pushed to the release, but rather to the next 8.5